# View hiding behind navigation bar android

Tags: android, android-view, navigationbar

I am using Sliding Activity,
the View is not fitting to the screen, it is hiding behind the Navigation Bar.

I tried ,

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item> 
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

but nothing works.

here Snackbar is hiding behind the Navigation Bar:
[image]

Comment: Please post your XML.

Answer (score 2):

Hey there best practive would be to use tha `NavigationDrawer`, but for your problem create a class `CustomSlidingMenu` which extends `SlidingMenu` and *Override* methods like this. Then use the `CustomSlidingMenu` instead of `SlidingMenu` and it should work fine

```
public class CustomSlidingMenu extends SlidingMenu {
    private boolean mActionbarOverlay = false;

    public CustomSlidingMenu(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSlidingMenu(Activity activity, int slideStyle) {
        super(activity, slideStyle);
    }

    public CustomSlidingMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSlidingMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected boolean fitSystemWindows(Rect insets) {
        if (mActionbarOverlay) return true;

        setMyPadding(insets);
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)
    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        if (mActionbarOverlay) return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();

        Rect rect = new Rect(
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft(),
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop(),
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight(),
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom()
        );

        setMyPadding(rect);

        return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
    }

    private void setMyPadding(Rect rect) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            switch (manager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    rect.right += getNavBarWidth();
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    rect.top += getNavBarHeight();
                    break;
                default:
                    rect.bottom += getNavBarHeight();
            }
        }

        setPadding(
                rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom
        );
    }

    private int getNavBarWidth() {
        return getNavBarDimen("navigation_bar_width");
    }

    private int getNavBarHeight() {
        return getNavBarDimen("navigation_bar_height");
    }

    private int getNavBarDimen(String resourceString) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        int id = r.getIdentifier(resourceString, "dimen", "android");
        if (id > 0) {
            return r.getDimensionPixelSize(id);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you use `AppCompat` with my approach, so the reason is that the paddings set by the `SlidingMenu` are in conflict with the `AppCompat` configurations and *Override* them.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. It works properly when navigation is visible but on Xiaomi devices with Pie when I use full screen gestures it shows the empty area of navigation bar in my app. Do you have any idea how to hide that empty navigation area?